# rxjava2 : concatenation of observables for paginated calls to DB

Tags: rx-java2, concatenation, pagination

I have a method that executes a paginated call to a database to collect data and return an observable.

```
public Observable search(string query, int limit, int offset)
```

I want to build a method that executes all paginated search calls to load all pages for my query and return a Completable. In this method I would like to concatenate all pages in one stream, executes reactive transformations and actions and return a completable.

However, as I have to deal with a huge quantity of data, I do not want to load all pages at the same time , put a huge quantity of data in memory and flood my reactive stream with a lot of data because my subscriber processes the data slower than the publisher.

So, I would like to process the first page of data, then load another page through a call to search method, process it and continue until I process the last page.

As I am in a reactive flux, I am not sure that it's a good idea to write a loop to : fetch the data, subscribe to the stream that will transform and process data.

My approach is to concatenate all the pages in one stream (using a method such as Observable.concat) and then process the stream. However I do not want to load a huge quantity of data in memory and get an outOfMemoryException.

Should I use a Flowable and use backpressure in a such situation?

What is the best way to do this with rxjava2?